# Which is proper listener to use doLayout function?

Tags: javascript, extjs, javascript-framework

I am working in EXTJs, Please check below example:

```
var containerForm=Ext.widget('panel',{ 
        width: 1100,
        border: false,
        frame: true,
        "layout":"fit",
        title: 'Add User',
        hidden:true,
        listeners:{
                'afterrender': function(panelObj,eOpts )
                {
                    panelObj.doLayout();
                }
        }
    });
```

Html of above panel is updating via ajax response as shown in the following code:

```
formObj.update(jsonResp.html,true,function(){
    containerForm.doLayout();containerForm.focus();
});
```

containerForm is auto height panel, because this panel is used for multiple pupose,

When "formObj.update" populating this panel content, it's content loading properly but

If ajax response "jsonResp.html" has any image, that time doLayout() function is not helping to align panel height properly,

i added doLayout function at 2 places but callback function is not helping me in above case:

when i call doLayout function after 2 seconds then only it's work correctly:

```
formObj.update(jsonResp.html,true,function(){
    setTimeout('containerForm.doLayout(); containerForm.focus();', 2000);
});
```

Which is proper listener to use doLayout function?

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at the [Mutation Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents) but these are not cross browser compatible.  If they were, you could try:
`formObj.on('DOMSubtreeModified', function(){containerForm.doLayout();}, this);`

You really just need to make sure your `formObj.update()` is complete.  That is why your timeout is helping.  If you want to make sure the innerHtml is set, just check it yourself.

If you look at the [Source for Ext.dom.Element.update()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/source/Element2.html#Ext-dom-Element-method-update), it is just using `dom.innerHtml` to update the html.  In your update callback, you could check to see if the innerHtml is there before calling `doLayout()`.  Some simple example code I threw together quick.

```
var doLayoutIfComplete = function(){
  if(document.getElementById('formObjId').innerHTML == jsonResp.html){
    containerForm.doLayout();
  }
  else{
    doLayoutWhenComplete.delay(500); //Check again in 500ms
  }
}

var doLayoutWhenComplete = new Ext.util.DelayedTask(function(){
  doLayoutIfComplete();     
});

formObj.update(jsonResp.html,true,function(){ 
  doLayoutWhenComplete.delay(500);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Justin for your answer, i will try this solution